# Program not counting number of records

Tags: c++, ifstream

I wrote a program that reads to one file, writes to another and prints to the screen.  In other words, it is supposed to do three things (i.e. read, write and print).

The program is also supposed to count the number of records in a file named "Chap_11_employee_data.txt".  It is just displaying the following, however.

```
**Total Records 0** 
    The End
```

When it writes to a file, it also displays weird numbers such as -858993460.  I have tried almost everything, which led me to register an account here.  My code is listed below as well as the file I am trying to read from and the file I am trying to write to.

Thank you very much for your guy's time.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  
#include <iomanip>  
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::ios;

using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;

const int EMPLOYEES = 20; 
const int MAX = 21;  

int ReadData( ifstream &inFile, ofstream &outFile, char name[][MAX], int age[] );
void WriteOutputFile( ofstream &outFile, char name[ ][MAX], int age[ ], int counter );
void PrintTotalsAndSummary( ofstream &out, int totalRecords );

int main()
{   
    char name[EMPLOYEES][MAX]; 
    int age[EMPLOYEES];
    int record_counter(0);

    ifstream inFile;    

    ofstream outFile( "Chap_11_Report.txt" );  

    inFile.open( "Chap_11_employee_data.txt" );  

    if ( inFile.is_open() )   
    {   
        record_counter = ReadData( inFile, outFile, name, age );
        inFile.close();

        if( outFile.is_open() )
        {   
            WriteOutputFile( outFile, name, age, record_counter );
            PrintTotalsAndSummary( outFile, record_counter );
            outFile.close();            
        }   
        else
        {   
            cout << "Trouble Opening File";  
            cout << "\n\n\t\t ** About to EXIT NOW! ** ";
        }   
    }   
    else
    {   
        cout << "Trouble Opening File";
        cout << "\n\n\t\t ** About to EXIT NOW! ** ";
    }   
    return 0;
}
int ReadData( ifstream & inFile, ofstream & outFile, char name[][MAX], int age[] )
{   
    int counter = 0;
    inFile >> name[counter] >> age[counter]; // Priming Read

    while ( !inFile.eof() )
    {
        cout << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw( 25 )
            <<  name[counter] << resetiosflags( ios::left )
            << setw( 4 ) << age [counter] << endl;
        counter++;
        inFile >> name[counter] >> age[counter];
    }

    return counter;
}


void WriteOutputFile( ofstream &outFile, char name[][MAX], int age[], int counter)
{
    outFile << "   Here is the Output File" << endl;
    for ( int r = 0; r <= counter; r++ )
    {
        outFile << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw( 25 )
            << name[r] << setw( 4 )
            << resetiosflags( ios::left ) << age[r]
            << endl;
    }
}

void PrintTotalsAndSummary( ofstream &outFile, int totalRecords )
{
    // To screen
    cout  << "\n\n\t** Total Records: " << totalRecords << " **\n"
        << "\t\t The End \n";

    // To file
    outFile << "\n\n\t** Total Records: " << totalRecords << " **\n"
        << "\t\t The End \n";
}
```

File I am reading from (Chap_11_employee_data.txt):

```
"Alexis","Blough",1-1921,"CEO"
"Bill","Pay",1-7711,"Accounting"
"Willy","Makit",4-1595,"Sales"
"Marie","Murray",1-4986,"MIS"
"Cal","Caldwellowinski",5-0911,"MIS"
"Jamie","Johanasola",5-9999,"Marketing"
```

File I am writing to (Chap_11_Report.txt):

```
Here is the Output File
                     -858993460


    ** Total Records: 0 **
         The End
```

Comment: Please remove tabs before inserting your code. It messes up the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your input statement...

```
inFile >> name[counter] >> age[counter];
```

And the output file format is this...

```
"Alexis","Blough",1-1921,"CEO"
"Bill","Pay",1-7711,"Accounting"
```

The input statement reads the name till it encounters a space or an endline character. So in the first case it would read the whole line as there is no space in between the words. Next on, it would take input of age which is an int. It would start taking input of age from the second line, which is full of characters from the beginning. A character in integer stream is undefined behavior. That is the reason you are getting wrong results.

The problem is the mismatch of the file format with the input format. Try to synchronise them.

For reading white spaces as well, use `inFile.get()` or `inFile.getline()`.

Comment: As an addendum, the OP's use of `counter` is horrible.  Make it actually count how many valid records there are.  So when `counter` is zero, there are zero valid records.  When `counter` is 1, there is one valid record.  As written, `counter` ends up equaling the number of valid records minus 1, with a min value of 0.

Comment: @Ralph Thank you very much for pointing out the inconsistency of my formatting.  I have since gotten rid of the commas and quotes and replaced them with spaces.

Comment: @Yakk -- Apologies since I am new to programming (freshman in college).  Should I make int counter = 1?

In any case, the file is still having problems counting any records.  I have a feeling it has to do with my while loop, but I have been looking at the code for over three hours and don't understand why it isn't incrementing the counter. :(

Comment: It is **not** undefined behavior. "Undefined Behavior" has a very specific meaning please use it correctly. Here we have bad input which set a bad state on the input stream (as defined by the method bad). Any operation on a bad stream results in a no op (which may leave values in an indeterminate state).

Comment: @LokiAstari Thank you very much for the input.  I believe I fixed the input stream (it now has spaces instead of commas), however, it still does not count any records.  

How do I make it so I don't have characters in my integer stream as Ralph was eluding to?

Comment: @mrpick the general pattern is to start count at zero.  Next do a while loop on end of input (such as file), and in that loop parse an entry keeping track of errors.  If you get an error, note it and break out of the loop.  Otherwise, increment count and store the record in your buffer (of whatever sort).  The idea is to maintain an invariant -- something that is true -- on each iteration of the loop.  In this case that count is the number of loaded records.

Answer (score 1):

Your read has one problem:

```
while ( !inFile.eof() )
```

The problem is that the stream can go bad in a way that is not eof(). If this happens you will enter an infinite loop. So really you should check for bad().

```
while ( !inFile.bad() ) // check for eof and other error cases.
```

Normally this test is completely wrong. But you have managed to get around this by doing the following:

```
<Get Input>

while ( !inFile.bad() )
{
    < DO WORK>
    <Get Input>
}
```

The same affect can be achieved (in a more idiomatic way) with:

```
while ( <Get Input> )
{
    < DO WORK>
}
```

The read (using >> or std::getline()) returns a reference to a stream. When this is used in a boolean context (like a while loop test) it is converted to bool (actually bool like for the language lawyers) that represents the state of the stream which is obtained by using bad. Thus the loop body is only entered if the read actually worked.

The input stream operators are very simplistic and any failure on input will set an internal failure bit inside the stream causing them to sieze up and not provide further input until the failure bit is reset.

Given the input you have provided this will fail:

```
inFile >> name[counter] >> age[counter];
```

The variable `name[counter]` represents a C-String and the the input operator >> when applied to a C-String will read until the first white space character (in this case newline). So here we assign:

```
"Alexis","Blough",1-1921,"CEO"
```

to this value.

We then try and continue reading using `age[counter]` an integer value. This tries to read an integer from:

```
"Bill","Pay",1-7711,"Accounting"
```

This will fail as the character `'"'` is not a digit.

What you should be doing is:

```
std::string  name;
std::getline(inFile, name, ','); // Read upto the ',' character (and discard it)
// You may want to remove the quotes here.

int age = 0;
// Age is not defined in the input so set it manually.

std::string  line;
std::getline(inFile, line);      // Read and ignore the rest of the line.
```

Comment: This should be enough for you to fix your code. When you get the code working. You may want to post your code here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get it reviewed. There are a couple of other things we can work on to make the code better but are not appropriate for the stackoverflow site.